# олимпиадная задача по c++ (двумерный массив)

Tags: c++, матрицы, олимпиада

**Условие:**
На квадратном клетчатом листе бумаги 8x8 клеток заштрихована часть клеток (пример на рисунке). Определить вписанный в решётку прямоугольник максимальной площади, не содержащий заштрихованных клеток. В качестве ответа вывести площадь прямоугольника и координаты его двух противоположных вершин. (Предполагается, что прямоугольник с максимальной площадью один.)

[image]

**Мое решение:** Для начала обозначил заштрихованные клетки единицами, а чистые - нулями. Получилась такая вот матрица:

[image]

Помеченный красным прямоугольник и есть **искомый ответ с координатами вершин (3,4) и (6,6)**, площадь 15 клеток.

**Код:** 
Функция которая определяет, имеется ли в заданном прямоугольнике заштрихованные поля. Если есть - возвращает false, если прямоугольник пустой - true

```
bool is_hatch(int arr[m][n])
{
    bool res = true;
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
        {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
            if(arr[i][j] == 1) res = false;
            else res = true;
            }
        }

return res;
}
```

**Вопрос:** Подскажите алгоритм уменьшения прямоугольника в случае если функция выдаст false, мои догадки только на том, чтобы левый верхний угол смещался вправо на 1 и вниз на 1. Точно так же правый нижний угол каждый раз смещался влево на 1 и вверх на 1 пока не найдется максимальная площадь с чистым полем. Но не знаю как реализовать это, хееелп

Comment: "красным прямоугольник" - " (3,4) и (7,6)"???

Comment: координаты его вершин

Comment: красным помечен другой прямоугольник

Comment: пардон, (3,4) и (6,6)

Comment: опять не то, правильный `(3,4) и (7,6)`, исправить надо картинку

Comment: Если доска всегда 8x8, то это не олимпиадная задача, а баловство. И решением здесь будет перебор всех возможных прямоугольников. Это будет, как мне кажется, быстрее оптимального алгоритма.

Comment: вы меня окончательно запутали

Comment: нет, не всегда. произвольное число >2 и < 100

Comment: Тогда смотрите [здесь](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/maximum_zero_submatrix).

Comment: то, что нужно. спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая размеры матрицы и скорость с++ (если я не ошибаюсь, 10 ^ 8 операций в секунду), можно просто перебрать все прямоугольники, всех возможных площадей (1 - 8). Сначала ищете 1 * 1, нашли - смотрите, насколько его можно расширить. Сохраняете площадь и вершины. Выходите за его пределы и повторяете (при этом в уже найденные прямоугольники не забывайте заходить). Ну, и, естественно, смотрите, если площадь нового прямоугольника больше максимума, максимальная_площадь = площадь, сохраняете координаты вершин. Повторять пока не закончится доска.